# Is there a way to do last_valid_index() in a rolling window?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

`last_valid_index()` only applies to the entire dataframe and `rolling()` does not allow `last_valid_index()`. Is there a way to find the last valid index in a column of booleans in a window?

For instance:

```
d = {'col': [True, False, True, True, False, False]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

The expected outcome for a rolling window of 3 is:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    2.0
3    3.0
4    3.0
5    3.0
```

Comment: I downvote for uncompleted question ,after edit I will correct the vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73604895/17333120), I think the current accepted solution has a bug. A lot of the beginning of this post is taken word-for-word from my comment there.

Change the example to be

```py
d = {'col': [True, False, True, True, False, False, False]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Then the last 3 entries compose the entire rolling window of 3, and all are False. But the current accepted solution returns index 3 for the last entry, even though I am assuming it should be NaN (otherwise what's the point of having the rolling window at all, other than to set the first 2 observations as NaN?).

Here is my proposed fix:

```py
df['new'] = df.index
df['new'] = df['new'].where(df['col'], -1).rolling(3).max().replace(-1, np.nan)
```

What it does is instead of replacing values where `df['col']` is False with NaNs, then using `ffill()` to replace those indices with the previous index, it replaces those indices with -1. Then at the end, if all the indices in a window have value -1, it means the entire window has `df['col']` as False, so that index is replaced with `np.nan`.

Comment: This sounds correct thanks, though I guess it could be a bit subjective, depended on what one needs the code for (for the original question: it's probably more accurate this way).

Answer (score 1):

We have some work around

```
df['new'] = df.index
df['new'].mask(df.youcol.isnull()).ffill().rolling(3).max()
```

From the comment

```
df['new'] = df.index
df['new'] = df['new'].where(df.col).ffill().rolling(3).max()
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    2.0
3    3.0
4    3.0
5    3.0
Name: new, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct. With "True,False,True,True,False,False" it returns "NaN, NaN, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 ,5.0". It's expected to return "NaN, NaN, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0".

Comment: @jriv you have not shared any information about your dataframe, please show the sample data to us

Comment: @jriv also you can check the update , but I still recommend edit your question adding more information

Comment: Thanks. That's great. I added the basic info of the comment to the OP.

Comment: Now I wonder how to do the same but for the second to last index that holds True.

Comment: A new question on that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67266021/

Comment: See the new answer here. There might be a bug here, though I guess it might depend on what one exactly needs from the code.