# Vectorized way to create a column based on indexes stored in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a column that stores the indexes of the last valid index of another column in a rolling window. This was done based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67199157/277716) answer.

So e.g. we had

```
d = {'col': [True, False, True, True, False, False]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

and then we got the last valid index in a rolling window with

```
df['new'] = df.index
df['new'] = df['new'].where(df.col).ffill().rolling(3).max()

0    NaN
1    NaN
2    2.0
3    3.0
4    3.0
5    3.0
```

How can I use those indexes to store to a new column `new_col` the values of a different column `col_b` in the same dataframe at the indexes recorded above?

e.g. if a different column `col_b` was

```
'col_b': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]
```

then the expected outcome of `new_col` based on the indexes above would be

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    300
3    400
4    400
5    400
```

PS. Let me know if it's easier to directly use the initial `col` for this purpose in some way (on a rolling window always)

Comment: I think there is a bug in your original code. Try e.g. `d = {'col': [True, False, True, True, False, False, False]}; df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)`. Then the last 3 entries compose the entire rolling window of 3, and all are False. But it returns index 3 for the last entry, even though I am assuming it should be NaN (otherwise what's the point of having the rolling window at all, other than to set the first 2 observations as NaN?).

Comment: I just posted a new solution to your original post that fixes the bug I mentioned in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work? What it does is use `df['new']` as the indices to access values from `df['col_b']`. This requires converting `df['new']` to int, so it has some intermediate steps of replacing the `nans` with `0s`, then putting the `nans` back into the new column.

```py
new_as_idx = df['new'].copy()
new_as_idx[np.isnan(new_as_idx)] = 0
new_as_idx = new_as_idx.astype(int)
new_b = df['col_b'].to_numpy()[new_as_idx]
new_b = new_b.astype('float')
new_b[np.isnan(df['new'])] = np.nan
df['new_b'] = new_b
```

Comment: Is the copying necessary? Also is it fully vectorized?

Comment: If you don't copy, it would overwrite the `nans` in the original dataframe. And I don't see what part of the code isn't vectorized, it's just using built-in numpy functions that are pretty basic. I don't know enough about the exact functions though, so I can't give a definitive answer of whether it's vectorized.

Comment: It appears to work. By the way: let me know if it would be simpler by using directly the initial `col` of the OP question, but it's already fine as it is I guess.

Comment: I'll accept this because it does exactly what the OP question asks. The other answer is good too, and it is re-doing the first part of the question if anyone needs that.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is create index by `col_b` and then call [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for indices by maximal values from original index:

```
df = df.set_index('col_b')
df['new']=df.index.to_series().where(df.col).ffill().rolling(3).apply(lambda x: x.idxmax())
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

print (df)
     col    new
0   True    NaN
1  False    NaN
2   True  300.0
3   True  400.0
4  False  400.0
5  False  400.0
```

In solution is possible add [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for values by `df['new']`, because duplicated index is necessary recreate original indices:

```
df['new'] = df[['col_b']].reindex(df['new']).set_index(df.index)
print (df)
     col  col_b    new
0   True    100    NaN
1  False    200    NaN
2   True    300  300.0
3   True    400  400.0
4  False    500  400.0
5  False    600  400.0
```

Or if always RangeIndex is posible use numpy indexing with remove missing values and casting to integers:

```
s = df['new'].dropna().astype(int)
df['new'] = pd.Series(df['col_b'].to_numpy()[s], index=s.index)
print (df)
     col  col_b    new
0   True    100    NaN
1  False    200    NaN
2   True    300  300.0
3   True    400  400.0
4  False    500  400.0
5  False    600  400.0
```

---

Btw, your solution is possible simplify:

```
df['new'] = df.index.to_series().where(df.col).ffill().rolling(3).max()
```

Comment: Isn't apply() non-vectorized? By the way: let me know if you think it could be done easier by using directly the initial `col` in the question instead of the resultant indexes (on a rolling window always).

Comment: @jriv - unfortunately not exist `rolling.idxmax`, so `apply` only way. Added another solution with your solution

Comment: Thanks, and I guess the second might be better for me, even if it's not exactly what I asked at the OP.

Comment: All 3 solutions appear to give "ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object".

Comment: @jriv - Error is with sample data?

Comment: Nevermind: I just had a typo at df.col. They all work fine thanks. Do you know by the way what's the most vectorized/faster way out of these (I guess the 2nd?)?

Comment: @jriv - In my opinion bottleneck here is `rolling`, the best test in real data which solution is fastest.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it's more related to the question (it does only the final part needed). This one is a very good answer too, and it is re-doing the first part of the question if someone needs that too (and in multiple ways on top).

Comment: @jriv - I understand - `df['new'] = df.index.to_series().where(df.col).ffill().rolling(3).max()` is used because simplier like `df['new'] = df.index
df['new'] = df['new'].where(df.col).ffill().rolling(3).max()`, it is only reason